# Replication in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have configured replication on my local machine. But the issue is that it worked fine when I configured it, but when I closed the cmd prompt, the servers were not starting. I started the secondary servers configured on ports 27020 and 27021, but they are not connecting. Also, when I began the primary server configured at 27017 port and ran the rs. Status () command gives an error msg indicating if there is no replication set exists. The snippets attached are showing the error messages when I wanted to start the primary and secondary servers.

[image: Primary Sever]
[image: Secondary Server]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: The error is quite obvious. Maybe have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick